# What's the strategy to implement single sign-on for two PHP websites?

Tags: php, drupal, single-sign-on

There are two websites, more are probably coming. One is a simple PHP site and the other is Drupal. The objectives are:

- to have two user accounts created when a new user registered on any website

optionally:

- when a user change a password on any website, the password is synced to another

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: You may also want to check out the Drupal Answers Beta site. The more people who use it, the better chance it has of making it past beta: http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas). There is a [drupal module](http://drupal.org/project/cas) and there is [phpCAS](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASC/phpCAS). This should work fine but this is no php-only solution. drupal.org itself uses [bakery](http://drupal.org/project/bakery) for SSO.

Answer (score 1):

First off you would need to make sure that both websites are able to connect to the same SQL database. If they have different domains you will need to choose one site to be the master gateway to login and checking if they are logged in.

Comment: maybe shared session on the database.

Answer (score 0):

this is Google's method which I think is great .... you can create your own `API` working the same way

[image]

Comment: If you do decide to use Google for authentication, you may want to check out this Drupal-centric "Overview of Google authentication methods": http://stellapower.net/blog/google-authentication-methods